# Is it really possible for hosting provider to know what you are hosting if you don't serve direct IP?

Tags: amazon-ec2, vps, hosting, azure

You can always configure Apache or Nginx to stop responding to request if it is accessed through direct IP, and only serve request targeted to your own domain name.

In this way, do hosting provider still have way to probe the requests that go through? If so how?

Answer (score 2):

It would be trivial to capture this information using a variety of monitoring software or packet analysis.

That said, I'm voting to close this question as off topic because it doesn't feel like a professional question.

Comment: Would you mind pointing out some the of mostly used softwares in this regard, so that I can take a deeper look?

Comment: @user2643506 I have no idea what hosting companies use, but Wireshark could pull the data pretty easily.